# How much of the loss of battery capacity in higher currents is caused by its internal heating?

Tags: batteries

For example [this page](https://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm) give this data for one AA battery:

```
0.5A : 1.84Ah
1A   : 1.411Ah
2A   : 1.18Ah
```

Is it mainly b/c of the internal heating?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature rise actually helps generate more power because the chemical diffusion and reactions are faster at higher temperatures (between 20 degrees and 30 degrees C the capacity goes up by 10%).  The loss of capacity is due to reaction products clogging up the surfaces, side reactions, and limited diffusion of reactants.

Comment: I think this is the only answer that is really on the money. Personally. Especially the side reactions. Anything that merely increases ESR cannot explain coulombic capacity loss.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite internal heating. But pretty close. It is due to the internal resistance bleeding off quadratically more power as heat with a linear increase in current draw. This will cause the battery to heat more, but you will see a decrease in capacity even if you if you magically keep the battery at the same temperature.

Comment: I don't understand your last remark - If I cool the battery by getting rid of the heat still there's energy loss via heat loss.AnywayiIs this all the lost energy?

Comment: The energy lost to the resistor does not depend on how fast the battery is discharged, does it? I think I calculated it one time. If there is a simple ESR that does not change as a function of current, then the energy lost to the resistor will only depend on how many coulombs pass through it, not how fast they pass. I could be wrong. Just throwing this out for your consideration. I may think it through more carefully and comment again later.

Comment: @OMGsh Last sentence is because you might think that just running the battery in a warmer environment might cause reduced capacity even at same current draw (well it might due to chemistry reasons, but it would not be because of the internal resistance).

Comment: @mkeith \$I^2R\$ so double the current four times the energy loss?

Comment: Yeah. Seems wrong. A 1 Ah battery with 1 Ohm resistor discharged at 1C would be 1 Wh of loss. Same battery discharged at 2C would be 4W * 0.5 hrs = 2 Wh of loss. So I am wrong. What I was thinking of was loss to ESR of a capacitor. I know the energy dissipated in the ESR does not depend on rate of capacitor discharge. That seems like an analogous case. I am pretty confused at the moment but will regain my senses soon.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Peukert’s Law? https://www.batterystuff.com/kb/tools/math-behind-the-magic.html

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Have not.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes, I have heard of Peukert's law. But this question is not about Peukert's law. It is about energy bookkeeping during discharge at different rates. Where does it go?

Comment: The double layer charge effects have higher ESR so you can imagine while the primary charge voltage slews faster the secondary losses increase by the square of dV/dt.  This also accounts for the memory effects from a pulsed short circuit. Peukert’s Law makes it useful for modelling the capacity losses.

Comment: _"you will see a decrease in capacity even if you if you magically keep the battery at the same temperature"_ - actually it could be _worse_, because the temperature rise increases ion mobility which lowers internal resistance.  A little self-heating in a cold battery can be good!

Comment: This graph gave me a double-take when I read GSM and NiCad , where I think latter is a typo error

Comment: One other thing to note: OP is asking about loss of coulombic capacity. Nothwithstanding my previous comments, coulombic capacity loss cannot be explained by a series resistor. So the loss of capacity is related to chemical processes somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The rate of discharge is directly proportional to the internal Ohmic losses inside the battery, because of which, the temperature of the battery also rises (decreasuing the output voltage in loaded condition). So, the available capacity reduces. same case with the aging of the battery where for a same contact load, there will be higher drop (loss) across the older battery than the new one.
[image]
Source: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/rising_internal_resistance

Comment: Series resistance cannot explain coulombic losses. No matter what the series resistance, it cannot somehow destroy charges that flow into it. There has to be coulombic loss inside the battery. I don't mean violation of  conservation of charge. I mean alternate chemical reactions which occur in the battery which consume electrochemical potential energy without causing current to flow outside the battery. In other words, side reactions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing here is  loss in capacity that is related to but not the same as the loss in energy.

The main reason is just that chemical reagents in the cell have limited speed of diffusion - putting an electrical load on the cell causes a chemical reaction. Fresh chemical need to diffuse into the active region of the cell for the voltage to be maintained.

A secondary reason for the capacity loss at higher currents is that the end-point is defined at a specific cell voltage - because of the drop across the cell's internal resistance will increase with the discharge current this will occur sooner at a higher discharge current.

For lead-acid batteries the capacity follows [Peukert's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law).

Comment: Regarding endpoint and ESR voltage drop, I have a question. Suppose I drain a lead acid battery at 1C for 50 minutes, then swicht to C/20. Will I get the same coulombic capacity as if I had discharged it at C/20 the whole time? Or is there something about high rate discharge of a lead acid battery that causes its coulombic efficiency to decline? In other words, are there internal side reactions during high rate discharge that rob you of coulombic capacity outright?

Comment: @mkeith - I don't think there are any such side reactions. If you let the battery rest (or use it at a low discharge rate) it will recover its capacity albeit slowly.

Comment: OK, so I discharge partially at high rate, then rest the battery for 24 hours, say, then finish the discharge at a low rate. You are saying that if I do that, you believe the capacity (in Amp-hours) will be the same (allowing for measurement uncertainty) as if I discharged continuously at a low rate? I am tempted to actually do this just to find out. I am sure someone must have written about this before, though.